# Build Bitcoin with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, bitcoin

I tried to compile bitcoin with cmake and I get the following error.

system info:

```
4.4.0-116-generic
cmake version 3.5.1
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10)
```

CMakeLists.txt (Demo)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12.2)

project(Bitcoin)

#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_definitions(-std=c++11)

......


get_property(dirs DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
foreach(dir ${dirs})
    message(STATUS "dir='${dir}'")
endforeach()

aux_source_directory(./src/ DIR_SRCS)

add_executable(bitcoin ${DIR_SRCS})
```

`cmake .`

> -- Configuring done
>
> -- Generating done
>
> -- Build files have been written to: /home/fyn/bitcoin

`make`

```
    In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:42:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/cstdlib:72,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:5249,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52,
                 from /home/youwei/bitcoin/src/fs.h:9,
                 from /home/youwei/bitcoin/src/fs.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/waitstatus.h:79:27: error: redeclaration of ‘unsigned int wait::<anonymous struct>::__w_retcode’
  unsigned int __w_retcode:8;
                           ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/waitstatus.h:74:27: note: previous declaration ‘unsigned int wait::<anonymous struct>::__w_retcode’
  unsigned int __w_retcode:8; /* Return code if exited normally.  */
                           ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/waitstatus.h:80:28: error: redeclaration of ‘unsigned int wait::<anonymous struct>::__w_coredump’
  unsigned int __w_coredump:1;

CMakeFiles/bitcoin.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/bitcoin.dir/src/fs.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/bitcoin.dir/src/fs.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/bitcoin.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/bitcoin.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: What is the question about?

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769348/error-compiling-duplicate-member-on-header-endian-h

Comment: What is this `Bitcoin` project? Can you post some links to repo? Did you follow the compilation instructions? Did you fetch the stable branch?

Comment: @Ptaq666 yes,ues this link https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin

Comment: Problem not reproduced. Most likely you have some libraries in your system that are not well designed and conflict with bitcoin code. It's difficult to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

You are clearly missing some libaries. Run

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --with-gui=no --disable-wallet
```

and check the logs (which will tell you which libaries are missing)

Edit: I suggest to remove `--with-gui=no --disable-wallet` if you want to know full compability.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into problems compiling bitcoin, as it has a lot of [dependencies](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/dependencies.md) but it turns out it has a [depends](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/depends/README.md) system built in to tackle that issue. It's best to utilize it when compiling. So, **from scratch**:

clone the bitcoin repo and build the depends system:

```
git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
cd bitcoin/depends
make
```

Once this completes successfully, you'll see a new folder in the depends directory with the name corresponding to your environment, e.g. `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`. Set the path to this folder when running `./configure` from the repository's root folder using the --prefix flag and run `make`:

```
cd ..
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=`pwd`/depends/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
make
```